# Ada pattern for bit fields

Tags: ada

In C, the use of bits in some form of unsigned char or int to represent non-exclusive conditions is very common and, by use of the & | and ~ operators, is extremely efficient. From my limited Ada experience, the equivalent in Ada would be as illustrated in the following code.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;   use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

   type Colours is (Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Yellow, Purple);

   type BitFieldType is array (Colours) of Boolean;
   pragma Pack (BitFieldType);

   RedBitField : constant BitFieldType := (Red => True, others => False);
   GreenBitField : constant BitFieldType := (Green => True, others => False);
   BlueBitField : constant BitFieldType := (Blue => True, others => False);
   OrangeBitField : constant BitFieldType := (Orange => True, others => False);
   YellowBitField : constant BitFieldType := (Yellow => True, others => False);
   PurpleBitField : constant BitFieldType := (Purple => True, others => False);
   NoColourBitField   : constant BitFieldType := (others => False);
   AllColoursBitField : constant BitFieldType := (others => True);

   MyBitField      : BitFieldType;
   MyOtherBitField : BitFieldType;
   Counter         : Integer := 0;

begin
   MyBitField      := not RedBitField;
   MyOtherBitField := RedBitField;

   if (MyOtherBitField or MyBitField) = AllColoursBitField then
      Counter := Counter + 1;
   end if;

   if (MyBitField and MyOtherBitField) = NoColourBitField then
      Counter := Counter + 1;
   end if;

   Put_Line ("Counter is " & Integer'image (Counter));

end Main;
```

This appears somewhat clunky. Is there a better and more Lovelacey way to use bit maps like this?

Comment: `pragma Pack` is a *hint* and the compiler is free to ignore it. You want to do `for BitFieldType'Component_Size use 1;` instead.

Comment: Not clunky at all! It is very practical, especially for large enumeration types. GNAT (and perhaps other compilers) produces very efficient machine code for that.

Comment: I just write Colour_Set instead of BitFieldType and Purple_Set (etc.) instead of PurpleBitField. You think more about the mathematical object and less about how it is implemented...

Answer (score 6):

What are you actually trying to achieve with your bitfields? You seem to want to write C using Ada. If that is true then consider using a modular type in Ada where you would use an unsigned type in C.

Section 4.5.1 of the Ada 2012 Reference Manual states:

> For modular types, the predefined logical operators are defined on a
> bit-by-bit basis, using the binary representation of the value of the
> operands to yield a binary representation for the result, where zero
> represents False and one represents True. If this result is outside
> the base range of the type, a final subtraction by the modulus is
> performed to bring the result into the base range of the type.
>
> The logical operators on arrays are performed on a
> component-by-component basis on matching components (as for equality —
> see 4.5.2), using the predefined logical operator for the component
> type. The bounds of the resulting array are those of the left operand.

For example, an unsigned type for your example could be defined as

```
type Color_Matrix is mod 2**6;
Red        : constant Color_Matrix := 2#100000#;
Green      : constant Color_Matrix := 2#010000#;
Blue       : constant Color_Matrix := 2#001000#;
Orange     : constant Color_Matrix := 2#000100#;
Yellow     : constant Color_Matrix := 2#000010#;
Purple     : constant Color_Matrix := 2#000001#;
No_Color   : constant Color_Matrix := 0;
All_Colors : constant Color_Matrix := 2#111111#;
```

You can now perform all your familiar operations on instances of Color_Matrix.

**Edit:**
Additional information comparing Ada represenation clauses and C/C++ bitfields can be found at https://sworthodoxy.blogspot.com/2014/03/ada-vs-c-bit-fields.html

Comment: Very easy to get those binary values wrong! (not as easy as in C where you have AFAIK to write them in hex)

Comment: True, but that is why I used binary representation and formatted the code to look like a table so that one can more easily visually check the values.

Answer (score 6):

It does depend what you are trying to do.

Often you'll see convoluted use of the `& | ~ << >>` operators (or sometimes even `&& ||`) and easy-to-get-wrong mask values in C to set, clear or test a single bit (e.g. turn RED on or off in a BitFieldType) instead of accessing the bit directly:

```
MyBitField(Red) := TRUE;
If MyBitField(Orange) then ...
```

Funnily enough, for microcontrollers with bit set, clear and test instructions, it's quite a difficult job for the compiler to translate the C code into the obvious simple instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I really should not be spending my Saturday doing pupils homework! ;-)

Try to move as much as possible to the declaration part. You may do something like this:

```
-- Warning: Not tested
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Bit_Fields is

   type Typ_Counter is range 0 .. 1_000_000; --  Fix this!
   package Counter_Io is new Ada.Text_Io.Integer_Io (Typ_Counter);

   procedure Increment (Counter : in out Typ_Counter; On_Condition : Boolean) is
   begin
      if On_Condition then
         Counter := Counter + 1;  --  May overflow!
      end if;
   end Increment;


   type Typ_Colour is mod 2**8 with Size => 8;  --  Look into this!

   Colour_Max  : constant Typ_Colour := Typ_Colour'Last;
   Colour_None : constant Typ_Colour := Typ_Colour'First;


   type Knd_Colour is (Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Yellow, Purple);
   type Arr_Colour is array (Knd_Colour) of Typ_Colour;

   None        : constant Arr_Colour := (others => Colour_None);
   Max         : constant Arr_Colour := (others => Colour_Max);

   generic
      with function Operation (Left, Right : Typ_Colour) return Typ_Colour;
   function Generic_Operation (Left, Right : Arr_Colour) return Arr_Colour;

   function Generic_Operation (Left, Right : Arr_Colour) return Arr_Colour
   is
      Result : Arr_Colour;
   begin
      for Gun in Result'Range loop
         Result (Gun) := Operation (Left  => Left  (Gun),
                                    Right => Right (Gun));
      end loop;
      return Result;
   end Generic_Operation;


   function "or"  is new Generic_Operation (Operation => "or");
   function "and" is new Generic_Operation (Operation => "and");

   My_Colours       : Arr_Colour;
   My_Other_Colours : Arr_Colour;
   Counter          : Typ_Counter := 0;
begin
   My_Colours       := (Red => not Colour_Max, others => Colour_None);
   My_Other_Colours := (Red => Colour_Max,     others => Colour_None);

   Increment (Counter, On => (My_Other_Colours or My_Colours)        = Max);
   Increment (Counter, On => (My_Colours       and My_Other_Colours) = None);

   declare
      use Ada.Text_Io, Counter_IO;
   begin
      Put ("Counter is ");
      Put (Counter, Width => 0);
      New_Line;
   end;

end Bit_Fields;
```